# When casting clone, does the actual clone continue to age after it matures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time, resurrection, aging

In [the description of the clone spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) it says about the clone:

> It remains inert and endures indefinitely

but that's it. Does the clone continue to age after it matured? Like if I created a 20 year old version of myself and 20 years later I die and my soul is sent to the cloned body. Did the clone age those extra 20 years? Is the clone now 40 years old?

Answer (score 4):

### The clone does not age as long as it stays in the vessel

From the spell description

> It remains inert and remains indefinitely, as long as its vessel remains undisturbed. (PHB Chapter 11, pg 222)

If the clone ages while in its vessel, it would likely not be considered "inert" and definitely could not "remain indefinitely" -- bodies stop functioning after a certain period of age, particularly for short-lived races like orcs and humans. There is no indication that they would continue to age if all other biological change was halted.